# Referring in EL to specific instance of h:datatable iteration variable

Tags: jsp, jsf

Okay. Complex Title for a simple(?) problem.

I have something like this going on (I made it as simple as possible here to illustrate)

```
<h:dataTable var="testVar" value="#{bean.VariablesArray}">
<h:inputText id="TestingID" 
             styleClass="propertyInput" 
             value="#{testVar.var1}"
         disabled="#{testVar.var2 != false }" 
             readonly="#{testVar.var2 != false }" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox 
             value="#{testVar.var2}">
         <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="TestingID" />
</h:dataTable>
```

It doesn't work and i'm assuming because of two reasons related to the datatable:

1. The EL `"#{testVar.var2 != false }"` should have a better instance indicator.
2. The `reRender="TestingID"` should be reffering to the correct instance of the inputText.

So my question is how do I do this correctly?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Uhm, those `#{}` things are not JavaScript, this is EL (Expression Language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/ajax-documentation/entire.html#d0e1657), `reRender` takes the form used by [UIComponent.findComponent(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) (that is, it uses the [client identifier](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) and not the [component identifier](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId%28%29)).

There are a few ways to get this value (combinations of backing beans, static functions and/or component binding) but you'll end up with something like this:

```
<h:inputText id="TestingID" styleClass="propertyInput" 
             value="#{testVar.var1}" disabled="#{testVar.var2 != false }" 
             readonly="#{testVar.var2 != false }"

             binding="#{someReqScopeMap.TestingID}" />

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testVar.var2}">
  <a4j:support event="onclick"
             reRender="#{myfn:cid(someReqScopeMap.TestingID)}" />
```

*See [JSF: working with component identifiers (id/clientId)](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html) for more detail and sample code.*